# Uniquely projective schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let us call a connected proper scheme $X$ over a field uniquely projective if all smooth very ample divisors of minimum $H^0$ are rationally equivalent (and at least one exists). I think the spectrum of the field is uniquely projective, so such schemes exist. What are some geometric properties ensuring unique projectivity of a smooth scheme? Question edited in response to abx's comments.

Comment: All (smooth) complete intersections of dimension $\geq 3$ in projective space have this property, and many others. No hope to classify!